# how to randomly filter and select a CGPoint from arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, filter, swift2

I have a number of arrays of CGPoints as shown in the method below. I am trying to filter a position for my sprite that moves down, left, up and right cyclically in the said order. How can randomly select an array from a array group (down, left etc) then randomly select a point from the selected array, also taking note of the array group so that when the method is called again the following group will be used for the generation (following the cyclical order). For example, since down is the first in the cycle, a "down array" is randomly selected and if say, down2 is chosen then a point should be randomly selected from down2, say p5. The next time that this method is called the same procedure should be followed for the "left array" and so on. It seems to be quite complex.

```
func nextPosition ()->CGPoint   {
        let down1 = [p1, p2]
        let down2 = [p3, p4, p5]
        let left1 = [p6, p7]
        let left2 = [p8, p9, p10]
        let left3 = [p11, p12, p13]
        let up1 = [p14, p15]
        let up2 = [p16, p17]
        let up3 = [p18, p19]
        let right1 = [p20, p21]
        let right2 = [p22, p23]
        let right3 = [p24, p25]
        let right4 = [p26, p27, p28, p29, p30]

        //return point    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
func nextPosition () -> CGPoint   {

    var pointsArray:[[CGPoint]] = [[]]

    let down1 = [p1, p2]
    pointsArray.append(down1)
    let down2 = [p3, p4, p5]
    pointsArray.append(down2)

    let left1 = [p6, p7]
    pointsArray.append(left1)
    let left2 = [p8, p9, p10]
    pointsArray.append(left2)
    let left3 = [p11, p12, p13]
    pointsArray.append(left3)

    let up1 = [p14, p15]
    pointsArray.append(up1)
    let up2 = [p16, p17]
    pointsArray.append(up2)
    let up3 = [p18, p19]
    pointsArray.append(up3)

    let right1 = [p20, p21]
    pointsArray.append(right1)
    let right2 = [p22, p23]
    pointsArray.append(right2)
    let right3 = [p24, p25]
    pointsArray.append(right3)
    let right4 = [p26, p27, p28, p29, p30]
    pointsArray.append(right4)


    let randomDirection: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(pointsArray.count)))
    let randomPoint: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(pointsArray[randomDirection].count)))

    return pointsArray[randomDirection][randomPoint]

}
```

What I am doing is basically creating a 2D array. The first dimension is for the direction, and the second dimension is for the point in that direction.

Comment: Appending first up array should be `up1` not `up11`. Would suggest an edit but it's only one char.

Comment: Yea sorry, typo, I fixed it.

Comment: Also this function is good for selecting a random variable out of every single point, but does not return 4 different points in order (one from down, left, up and right).

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite understand the question. But from this, it really shouldn't be a problem to select 4 different points, and return an array.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. The return from the function is an array of 4 CGPoints - the next four points, one of each direction, i.e. the first is a down point, the next is a left point etc. An example return from the function could be `[p3, p7, p19, p25]`.

```
func nextPosition() -> [CGPoint] {

    // Make a separate array for each group of points in each direction
    let down1 = [p1, p2]
    let down2 = [p3, p4, p5]
    let left1 = [p6, p7]
    let left2 = [p8, p9, p10]
    let left3 = [p11, p12, p13]
    let up1 = [p14, p15]
    let up2 = [p16, p17]
    let up3 = [p18, p19]
    let right1 = [p20, p21]
    let right2 = [p22, p23]
    let right3 = [p24, p25]
    let right4 = [p26, p27, p28, p29, p30]

    // Make separate arrays for each direction which contains the previous arrays
    let dArray = [down1, down2]
    let lArray = [left1, left2, left3]
    let uArray = [up1, up2, up3]
    let rArray = [right1, right2, right3, right4]

    // Make an array to group all the directions
    let array = [dArray, lArray, uArray, rArray]

    var nextPositions = [CGPoint]()

    // loop through dArray, lArray etc.
    for arr in array {
        // pick random direction array
        var length = UInt32(arr.count)
        let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(length))

        // pick random point from sub array
        length =  UInt32(arr[random].count)
        let random2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(length))

        // print final random point
        print(arr[random][random2])
        nextPositions.append(arr[random][random2])
    }
    return nextPositions
}
```